# Trouble using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to use NSDateFormatter to convert an NSString like 2013-02-08T10:50:00.000 to 10:50AM, no matter what I do I can't seem to get the AM or to get it to work with something over 12 (2013-02-08T15:00:00.000) any ideas?

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH-mm"];
    NSString *datelocalformat= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:DepartTimeString];
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried that failed?

Comment: Look at the spec for NSDateFormatter and follow the hot links in the description until you find the formatter string spec.  (You have to follow about 4 links.)  You will find that "HH" gives you 24-hour time.  (Or, I suppose if you whine enough, someone else will do your work for you.)

Comment: Calm down, I posted on here after finding no results from research. Do you mean on the Apple Developer Library?

Comment: Yes, the online specs.  Granted, access is a little clumsy, but if you start [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and use the search box in the upper right you can get to the specs for all the classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];//get today's date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter release];

// Get time - display in 12HR
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[timeFormatter release];
```